# How to keep this factory logic in one place?

Tags: c++, interface, factory

I have 2 classes: Bar and Foo.

They both derive **only** the 2 interfaces: IActions and IOtherActions.

So we have something like:

```
class Bar : public IActions ,public IOtherActions

class Foo : public IActions ,public IOtherActions
```

Now I have a factory where I have the logic to decide if Foo or Bar is going to be used.

```
IActions* getActions();
IOtherActions* getOtherActions();
```

My issue is that what's inside getActions() and what's inside getOtherActions() is the exact same logic.

```
IActions* getActions()
{
    // not trivial logic to decide which one to use and to create the instance
    return instancePointer;
}
```

As I said, getOtherActions() would just be a copy-paste of getActions() with the return type being different.

Is there any way to keep the logic in one place?

Comment: Yes I thought about it but I wanted to make sure I haven't missed something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least at first glance, it looks like you can use a template (which you'll explicitly instantiate for each return type):

```
template <class T>
T *getActions() { 
    // non-trivial logic
    return isntancePointer;
}
```

...which will then be instantiated as `getActions<IActions *>` and `getActions<IOtherActions *>`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create an intermediate type that you can cast to the needed interface:

```
class IFooBar: public IActions, public IOtherActions {};

class Foo: public IFooBar // ...
class Bar: public IFooBar // ...

IFooBar* getFooOrBar() {
    // nontrivial logic here
}

IActions *getActions() {
    return getFooOrBar();
}

IOtherActions *getOtherActions() {
    return getFooOrBar();
}
```